# Does connection to torrent peers slow down internet?

Tags: networking, home-networking

I currently run torrents every so often.  My internet speed is 50Mb/s down, 3Mb/s up.

I don't want my torrenting to affect the speed of other people on my network, so I usually set a maximum download of 500KB/s and a maximum upload of 40KB/s.  However, I was told by someone else using my network that just being connected to many peers itself could slow down the internet to a noticeable effect.

I tried to google the answer, but I couldn't find anything.  My question is:  In my case, with a bandwidth limit well below my maximum, would the sheer connection to my peers slow the internet for other users? With the bandwidth limit on, should users experience slow connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ISP's limit the number of connections from a location.  So theoretically, it could cause issues as your torrent connections could compete with another connection for a slot.

One easy fix is limiting your number of connections, or "work" on down-times (i.e. over night).

Comment: That was not a limit on the number of connections, it was a limit on the number of devices.

Comment: Oops, misread.  I guess that's what I get while I am trying to figure out gentoo at the same time.  Thanks @DavidSchwartz